# Testing singleton initialization and throwing appropriate exceptions

Tags: powershell, singleton

I am continuing to try to grok a singleton implementation with PowerShell classes, and having issues now with handling exceptions.
My test singleton needs to be initialized the first time with a list of files to process, and all following references should have no arguments, since I never want to reprocess files, just reference what was processed initially. To that end I have this...

```
class TestClass {
    # Properties
    [collections.arrayList]$Files = [collections.arrayList]::New()
    static [TestClass] $instance = $null

    # Constructor
    TestClass([string[]]$filePaths){
        foreach ($path in $filePaths) {
            $this.Files.Add("$($path): Processed")
        }
    }

    [void] ListFiles() {
        foreach ($processedFile in $this.Files) {
            Write-Host "$processedFile!"
        }
    }

    # Singleton Methods
    static [TestClass] GetInstance() {
        if ([TestClass]::Instance -ne $null) {
            $caller = (Get-PSCallStack)[-1]
            throw "Px Tools Exception: Singleton must be initialized ($caller)"
        } 
        return [TestClass]::Instance
    }
    static [TestClass] GetInstance([string[]]$filePaths) {
        if ([TestClass]::Instance -eq $null) {
            [TestClass]::Instance = [TestClass]::New($filePaths)
        } else {
            $caller = (Get-PSCallStack)[-1]
            throw "Px Tools Exception: Singleton cannot be reinitialized ($caller)"
        }
        return [TestClass]::Instance
    }
}
```

A properly done first initialization works, i.e.

```
$firstInstance = [TestClass]::GetInstance($unprocessedFiles)
$firstInstance.ListFiles()
```

will initialize the singleton and list the files. So the conditional `if ([TestClass]::Instance -eq $null)` works.

Also, if I try to reinitialize like this

```
$firstInstance = [TestClass]::GetInstance($unprocessedFiles)
$secondInstance = [TestClass]::GetInstance($unprocessedFiles)
```

I get the appropriate

> Exception: Singleton cannot be reinitialized

However, if I make the first reference without the files to process, like this...

```
$firstInstance = [TestClass]::GetInstance()
```

I get no error. So, why does `if ([TestClass]::Instance -eq $null)` seem to work correctly but `if ([TestClass]::Instance -ne $null)` does not? And, is there a better way to address this? I thought perhaps I could test the $Files property, either for $null or a Count of 0, but I can't reference a non static property from a static method, so barring the kludgy approach of a static $Initialized property, what is the solution?

EDIT: Duh. Hopefully this helps someone else. Don't test for the value, test for existence, like this.

```
if (-not [TestClass]::Instance) {
```

Comment: ```$null``` comparison in PowerShell can be fickle:```$null -eq @()``` => ```False```, but ```@() -eq $null``` => ```$null``` (not ```$true``` or ```$false```!). It's best practice to put ```$null``` on the left hand side - e.g. ```($null -eq [TestClass]::Instance)``` to get more predictable behaviour, although that might not be the exact issue you had in this case. See https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/RuleDocumentation/PossibleIncorrectComparisonWithNull.md for more info.

Comment: @mclayton Now that $null on the Left advice sounds REALLY useful, in a lot of places. I'll need to keep an eye out for those situations as I refactor, and see if moving things around helps any other squarely issues I have.

Comment: running PSScriptAnalyzer on your code is a really good way to catch a lot of those types of hard-to-diagnose issues...